# php header location not working as it should

Tags: php, header

i have the following code to detect the current logged in user:

```
$friends = array('1','4');
$user = $_GET['userID'];
if(!in_array($user, $friends)){

    header('Location: http://example.org/messages');
    echo $user;

}
```

In the above i am checking if the user is not in the `$friends` array. The user is question has an id of 5 so does not exist.

For some strange reason, when i echo `$user` this works, but trying to redirect the user doesnt.

Any ideas why this could be?

Comment: You should exit after setting a redirection header, otherwise the script will continue to execute and send any further output to the browser before the browser is able to act on the redirect

Comment: Add error reporting `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and chances are, you'll get a `Headers already sent...` error message. I've tested this without a hitch.

Answer (score 1):

A header cannot be set if something else has already been sent to the header.

You could try flushing the OB by putting this at the top of your code?

```
ob_flush();
```